# When running a springboot app - using spring 5 - how are apache nio properties configured?

Tags: spring-boot, nio

We are running a springboot application using the new reactive features. For downstream calls we are using the new WebClient provided by spring. When we configure the max threads - the configuration is honored. We would like to experiment with additional poller threads or changing some of the timeouts. However the nio specific apache configuration is not honored.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

in application.properties

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=3 <- this is working
server.tomcat.accept-count=1000 <- this is working
server.tomcat.poller-thread-count=5 <- this is not working/ignored
server.tomcat.poller-thread-priority=5 <- this is not working/ignored
server.tomcat.selector-timeout=2000 <- this is not working/ignored
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Connector that is used by Tomcat , e.g the NIO connector can be configured
by providing your own Customizer :

```
@Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> 
        ((AbstractProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxConnections(200));


        // configure some more properties

        return factory;
    }
}
```

You can also read:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-tomcat